# Kafka Consumer in play framework using java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, playframework, kafka-consumer-api

I have searched thousands of sites for kafka consumer example in play framework in java language. But not able to find any example. Can anyone provide details on how to write a service which consumes topics produced by kafka continuously.

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you added your existing code into the question

Answer (score 2):

Recently I have faced a similar issue, so I will add few notes after my researches.

I will describe how to use plain KafkaConsumer in Play Framework (but in scala not Java). It is always worth to know how lower-level components works, but after all I strongly encourage you to consider use libraries like [Alpakka](https://stepniewski.tech/L/voELbvpr). For example in my last project I decided to use [akka-projection](https://stepniewski.tech/L/2iFMeunap) which is build on Alpakka. It composes with Akka nicely and give you some extra value like easy configuration of restart strategy in case of failure.

To use plain KafkaConsumer in Play Framework:

1. Create Singleton which will manage `KafkaConsumer`. In the following example `while` loop runs in dedicated thread. Plain `KafkaConsumer` is closed during application shutdown.

```scala
@Singleton
class SampleKafkaConsumer @Inject()(coordinatedShutdown: CoordinatedShutdown) extends Logging {

  logger.info("SampleKafkaConsumer starts")

  private val executionContext: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
  private val stopConsumer: AtomicBoolean = new AtomicBoolean(false)

  private val properties = new Properties()
  properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:6003")
  properties.put("group.id", s"sample-group-id")
  properties.put("key.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])
  properties.put("value.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])

  val kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](properties)
  kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Set("sample-topic").asJava)

  Future {
    while (!stopConsumer.get()) {
      kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).asScala
        .foreach(r => {
          logger.info(s"SampleKafkaConsumer receives record: $r")
        })
    }
    logger.info(s"SampleKafkaConsumer quits 'while(true)' loop.")
  }(executionContext)
  .andThen(_ => kafkaConsumer.close())(executionContext)
  .andThen {
    case Success(_) =>
      logger.info(s"SampleKafkaConsumer succeed.")
    case Failure(e) =>
      logger.error(s"SampleKafkaConsumer fails.", e)
  }(executionContext)

  coordinatedShutdown.addTask(CoordinatedShutdown.PhaseServiceStop, "SampleKafkaConsumer-stop"){() =>
    logger.info("Shutdown-task[SampleKafkaConsumer-stop] starts.")
    stopConsumer.set(true)
    Future{ Done }(executionContext).andThen{
      case Success(_) => logger.info("Shutdown-task[SampleKafkaConsumer-stop] succeed.")
      case Failure(e) => logger.error("Shutdown-task[SampleKafkaConsumer-stop] fails.", e)
    }(executionContext)
  }
}
```

2. Mark it as "eager" using play module:

```scala
class KafkaModule extends AbstractModule with Logging {

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    logger.info("Starting KafkaModule")
    bind(classOf[SampleKafkaConsumer]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

3.Enable your module in play config file:

```yaml
play.modules.enabled += "kafka.KafkaModule
```

And it is all. I described everything in details [here](https://stepniewski.tech/L/3GG49Q2F).

Answer (score 0):

Play is a web-framework. The underlying Actor system relies on Akka.

The Akka Kafka API [is called Alpakka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/consumer.html), so I suspect you are searching in the wrong keywords

To combine both Akka and Play w/ Kafka, you can even use the [Lagom Framework](https://www.lagomframework.com/)

---

Otherwise, of course you can use plain Java consumer as well, regardless of Play Framework

> provide details on how to write a service which consumes topics produced by kafka continuously

```
KafkaConsumer c = new KafkaConsumer(props);
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords r = c.poll(1000);
    ...
}
```

Comment: My intention here is, I need to write code in existing web application which is on play framework. When server starts my code needs to listen to kafka topic. if kafka produces some message, my code need to react according to the message.

Comment: Okay, and Akka Streams (or raw kafka api) is perfectly capable of that. Was there a question there?

Comment: I didn't find proper documentation on how to implement it. I need to listen continuously to kafka topic. In Spring we have @kafkalistener where it will listen continuously to topics provided.

Comment: You create a `Consumer` https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/consumer.html#consume- and `Source`. The default is to always listen. https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/subscription.html

Comment: I am not able to understand from these docs. Any working sample is present please provide.

Comment: How to create consumer,,and how it will default listen

Comment: There's snippets of code all over that site. And again, what's stopping you from even making a plain `new KafkaConsumer()`? It listens by default because that's just how the API works

Comment: Here's one example on Github I was able to find. https://gist.github.com/stefanobaghino/853c45f6355ad3a21b1f

Comment: I have written the code in controller method as specified in site. Whenever I produce a message in kafka, my controller code is not getting invoked. Can you help me how to connect both of these

Comment: The reference you provide is in scala, Not sure how to map that with java code. Thanks for your help

Comment: How about this example? https://github.com/lagom/lagom-samples/blob/1.6.x/shopping-cart/shopping-cart-java/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But it didn't helped me much.

Comment: Can you explain why? If you want to use Play and Kafka, the Lagom Framework was made with that purpose https://www.lagomframework.com/ & https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/MessageBroker.html